# Using variadic arguments in an override of a (non-variadic) method

Tags: php, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm trying to override a class that uses a traditional argument list. To allow for changes to the underlying method's signature (which I can't control and which is liable to change, but I do need to override it), I had been trying to use variadic arguments, as so:

```
class A {
    public function demo($a) {}
}

class B extends A {
    public function demo(...$args) {}
}
```

However, this emits a strict error,

```
Declaration of B::demo(...$args) should be compatible with A::demo($b)
```

Based on my understanding of the Liskov substitution principle, my code ought to be permitted - any code that expected to call `A::demo` could safely call `B::demo`, without generating any errors.

Is there a misunderstanding on my end, or is it just that nobody bothered to implement support for this (presumably) edge case in the PHP compiler?

I'm aware that I can use `func_get_args()` instead, to emulate this behaviour without angering the compiler, but I would like to know why this approach doesn't work (and func_get_args is slower).

Comment: "...$args" would allow also no args at all, so both are not really the same I'd say.

Comment: @Yoshi They aren't meant to be exactly the same though, you just need to accept at least as many arguments as the original and not require more, so that any code that expects `A` will work fine with `B`, as would be the case here. If you add an optional argument `$a = null` at the start of `B::demo`, it works without emitting any errors, even though that also allows you to pass no args at all.

Comment: Fixed by https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/5059, likely to be available in PHP 8.